# Updating copyright note in a batch of latex files?

Tags: source

Appologising in advance for profound ignorance

here is my problem.  My 86 year old Dad has created a beautiful, free academic website, [www.earlymoderntexts.com](http://www.earlymoderntexts.com/). He created all the text files in Latex, and converted to PDF. I need to amend/update the copyright line on all the files, probably about 1,000 files.  I can hire someone to do that but my Dad thinks this is problematic because the person won't have "HIS" version of Latex with all the specialized Latex files he uses.

Oy.

Does this make sense?  Is there an easy work-around, so a 3rd party can make LaTex do the same things it does in my Dad's version?

Apologies for ignorance.

Comment: Run an `sed` script or something? This question has nothing to do with LaTeX i think.

Comment: Just to update the files introducing a new copyright notice one doesn't need to actually run LaTeX and therefore doesn't need the packages created by your Dad.

Comment: Is it is "fee" academic web site or a "free" one? :) I suspect the latter. To help you we need more detail. How does the copyright statement appear at the moment? How should it be changed? What `\documentclass` etc are you using. At a minimum we also need a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: Compliments to your dad!

Comment: I just looked at the site. These are all old texts that are out of copyright - that is exactly why your dad could republish them. His copyright notices are spurious and shouldn't be "updated" but rather removed. See http://www.nyulawreview.org/sites/default/files/pdf/NYULawReview-81-3-Mazzone.pdf

Comment: it's possible to edit pdf files directly with adobe acrobat pro.  not free, and i've no idea how much a license costs, but it might be less than the time required to rerun everything through latex, and i believe there is an academic discount that might be available.  there might also be other pdf-editing tools available, and i'd look for those.

Comment: Oy.  The site is Free, you are right.  I guess I don't know enough to ask the right question.  The change to the pdf is trivial, My dad, who is smart but old, seems to think no-one else will be able to do this, because when he converts to PDF, LaTex "calls up" - dozens of extremely specialized files. I'm thinking, that can not be right.  I want to take this long job off his plate. I fear my question is the Latex equivalent of asking, "Where is the 'on' button?""calls up" - dozens of extremely specialized files.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer While I agree that copyfraud is everywhere, I'm not sure you can infer that the notices should be purely removed: the editor might want to add "Public domain" for the original text, and whatever licence he chose for his annotations. I think this would make sense, and would deserve to be spelled out.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer "These are all old texts that are out of copyright" - that does *not* seem to be the case. The original texts have been "translated into modern English" and as such (under UK copyright law since they appear to be associated with Oxford university) your grandfather will certainly hold copyright of the translation, unless he has assigned it to someone else or given it away for free. See the FAQ on the site for more details.

Comment: @alephzero - you are right. I overlooked the fact that these texts have been extensively edited. Still, the copyright statement in its current form is still to broad and misleading, since these are mostly *not* actual translations.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Academic discounts for faculty are a US thing. Good luck getting one on anything in the UK.

Comment: What would be most excellent would be if you could also persuade him to make the LaTeX source available. Currently, I convert his PDFs to text and then redo the mark-up in LaTeX to get as close a match as I can. This is, needless to say, highly error-prone. In fact, by this point, I have a set of macros which reproduce the mark-up pretty well. It is just needing to pick out visually all the bits where it needs applying that is tricky. Given the source, it would be relatively straightforward even without your dad's macros. Given the macros also, it should be very simple.

Comment: I say this because I once asked your dad if he would consider making the source available, but I could not persuade him because he didn't think it would be useful without his special stuff (and I suspect he thought he'd need to tidy it up). If that really is the concern, I want to reiterate that the usefulness of the texts would be greatly increased by the availability of even messy, non-compilable source. (Compilable would obviously be even better.)

Comment: That said, you probably just need a `sed` or `gawk` script to amend the notices and a shell script to recompile the sources. Unlikely you need to hire anybody to do that - it should be a pretty trivial job, as long as there is a reasonable pattern to the notices and the changes needed.

Comment: @cfr -- fair enough (corporate policies u.s. vs. u.k.); when i made the comment, the link to the web site wasn't visible, and i had no way of knowing where the op was located.  however, i still think that this sort of modification is probably not unusual, and there might be a freeware pdf editing tool that makes it possible, so that's what i would look for.

Comment: @barbarabeeton There may be something for Windows. I can't say I've found anything for Linux.

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be some misunderstandings here. I would guess the situation is that your grandfather is an expert in early modern texts on philosophy, but not on how LaTeX works, even though he has used it a lot!

If he wants to allow someone else to re-compile the text direct from LaTeX, all he needs to do is provide a copy of all "his special version" files as well as the source of the actual text. So far as LaTeX is concerned, those "special files" are just more input. If he has actually modified the LaTeX program by changing the C source code of the program(s) and recompiling them (very unlikely, put theoretically possible!) that doesn't apply, of course.

If this had been done in a well-structured manner, there might only be one (very short) file containing the copyright text for all the books in any case - in which case the modification is trivial. There are also ways to automate re-generating 1,000 documents without typing almost the same command 1,000 times, of course - but those are not specific to LaTeX, and if he created the documents one by one over a number of years, he might never have felt the need to explore those.